# Angular2 Library to upload files

Tags: angular, upload

I have been looking into a library to upload files in Angular2.
The 2 standouts I did find are : `ng2-file-upload` and `ng2-uploader`.

I did look at their github :
https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader
and 
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload

Both seems to be able to do what I need (drag and drop uploading), but I am not sure which was is the most "stable". Any feedbacks on these 2 (or any other) would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader seems promising and recently updated

Comment: This is not really a question we can answer, but according to a few details like last commit, numbers of developper, number of contributor. I would go for [ng2-uploader](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader).